# Using Python's smtplib with Tor

Tags: python, smtp, tor

I'm conducting experiments regarding e-mail spam. One of these experiments require sending mail thru Tor. Since I'm using Python and smtplib for my experiments, I'm looking for a way to use the Tor proxy (or other method) to perform that mail sending.
Ideas how this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of abuse by spammers, many Tor egress nodes decline to emit port 25 (SMTP) traffic, so you may have problems.

Comment: Ancient post but not answering the question at all.

Answer (score 1):

http://bent.latency.net/smtpprox/ I found this earlier, but haven't tried it